# Does iPad battery charging utility like Battery Boost Magic pro really make a difference in prolonging iPad's battery life?

Tags: ipad, applications, battery, charging

Do battery charging utilities such as Battery Boost Magic pro or Kingsoft battery doctor really make a difference in prolonging the life of an iPad battery?

Comment: This is a great question. I have seen their claims about that and been curious myself. Instinct would tell me that there is no battery life improvement to speak of. Perhaps there is some trick they have figured out to slightly improve battery life in some, rare situations, but chances are the apps really don't do much other then tell you how much battery is left. And, it seems, if it was true, that Apple would "borrow" those ideas for iOS itself, but that part is just conjecture.

Comment: Are you looking for tools to change your behavior or expecting these to somehow adjust the power usage on the device itself? Those that do the former can be helpful, the others are more akin to snake oil since they don't really explain how they work.

Comment: @bmike they explain how they work by saying it's a trickle charge, taper charge etc etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it really can't. What it can do, is show you how much battery the device has left, and hence motivate you to conserve battery with dimming the screen, and perform activities that are less battery intensive.

Apps in iOS are sandboxed heavily and consequently can't perform system-level functions that might possibly be used to conserve battery. The other problem with this sandboxing is it would likely mean any battery conservation would have to happen while the app is open, and the device unlocked. iOS 5 allows certain processes to continue running in the background, but those include things like using the accelerometer, GPS, and such. This again comes back to iOS apps not allowing access to many system-level processes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it does not work you should delete the app quickly and report it to Apple to get your money back.